# A value of type '_ChangeCountryPageState' can't be returned from the method 'createState' because it has a return type of 'State<ChangeCountryPage>'

Tags: flutter, macos

```
import 'package:ecommerce_int2/app_properties.dart';
import 'package:ecommerce_int2/screens/settings/change_country.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class ChangeLanguagePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChangeLanguagePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ChangeCountryPage> createState() => _ChangeCountryPageState();
}
```

This is the snippit to my code. This page is suppose to help select Different languages from a pre-given list but I'm getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't showed it but `_ChangeCountryPageState` needs to extend `State<ChangeCountryPage>` so like

```
class _ChangeCountryPageState extends State<ChangeCountryPage> {
```

The error must mean that you are not doing that.

But it also seems you are mixing up two pages. This is `ChangeLanguagePage` but you are returning `State<ChangeCountryPage>` for the `createState()` but this should be `State<ChangeLanguagePage>` then

Comment: That worked. Appreciate your help